# Regex to detect file hash string

Tags: c#, regex

I have files named like this:

//Should detect as filehash name

98-80-7D-E5-50-A1-73-59-7F-FC-1C-CB-10-0F-39-D7-C2-97-88-44.zip

//Should detect as non-hash name

model.zip

I want to detect in C# that the file name is hash value or not?
How do I detect such string? So far I've used following but it does not work.

```
private static bool IsFileHash(string input)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will match a hash name : `(\w{2}\-)*(\w){2}`

```js
const text = "98-80-7D-E5-50-A1-73-59-7F-FC-1C-CB-10-0F-39-D7-C2-97-88-44"

const regex = /(\w{2}\-)*(\w){2}/g;

console.log(text.match(regex));
```

Comment: This answer seems to be the most simple compared to other answers.

Comment: @ZackISSOIR However, `(\w{2}\-)*(\w){2}` will also match strings like `.m#@%@EYTFC54`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FrcxLd/1). `Regex.IsMatch` can match partial substrings. That is let alone that `\w` matches all Unicode letters, digits, diacritics, etc.

Comment: i don't want to spoil the party, but this would not just strictly match (hexadecimal) hash values, but also things like `gh-er`, for example (which could be a valid file name OP could perhaps come across). Anyway, it's of course up to OP to decider whether they want to tolerate possible false positives or not...